# How can I avoid timeout errors while debugging a web service in visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, web-services

I am using a console application to call web service methods and I am stepping through the code using the debugger in vs2008.

Sometimes I need to stop and think about things, and compare values. Not talking hours, just a few minutes, at this point the web service times out, how can I avoid this, so that the web service does not time out at all.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, now a serious answer, found at:

http://bytes.com/groups/net-web-services/628561-increase-default-webservice-timeout-globally

1. Increase the [`Timeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47096yt2.aspx) property of the web-service-proxy.

   ```
   MyWebServ obj = new MyWebServ();
   obj.Timeout = -1; // -1 for forever otherwise in milliseconds
   ```
2. Increase the timeout value in http-runtime tag in web-config of ASP.NET
   project./app.config if the web consumer application is Windows.
3. Increase the timeout value in http-runtime tag in web-config of Web Services
   project.

Answer (score 5):

You can turn the timeout off by stopping the application pool from recycling:

In the IIS console, go to the app pool properties and set "Ping Enabled" to false

(hope this helps! - is my first answer on here)

Comment: It appears I can't put a comment anywhere else apparently, so will comment here.  Would this solution not ultimately be slightly better as it involves no code changes (or config file changes), so when you deploy it to a live environment there's no risk of accidentally leaving the unlimited timeout in your app?

Comment: I'm years late to the game here but looking at the same nuisance as the OP.  I'll just post this comment for anyone else who follows me.  I am not (and I believe he was not) interested in the timeout/recycling of the ApplicationPool.  This is an exception received in response to a single request that times out because I've set a breakpoint in the web service side.  The default timeout appears to be 30 seconds after which it's too late to resume debugging my request because of the WebException (timeout) thrown in the client proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I hade the [same Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338359/configuring-the-timeout-period-for-debugger-in-vs2008) and in my case the Solutions mentioned here did not really help.

After long searching time i found the solution somewhere else, i had to disable worker process pinging for an Application pool by following command:

```
appcmd set apppool /apppool.name: string /processModel.pingingEnabled: false
```

alternativly you can configure this in the User Interface by:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. On the Connections pane, expand the server node and click Application Pools.
3. On the Application Pools page, select the application pool and then click Advanced Settings in the Actions pane.
4. For the Pinging Enabled property, select False to disable pinging, and then click OK.