# Configuring the Timeout-period for Debugger in VS2008

Tags: delphi, visual-studio-2008, debugging, timeout

Im using a C#-Service in a Delphi application, the problem is that VS stops the debugger if i dont click anything for some time.

It looks like a debugging-timeout issue but i can not find any related configuration in VS for this. Does anybody know if there is such a Configuration and where is it?

Thanks for your Help.

Comment: Interesting. Never heard of a debugger timeout. Had it running (stalled on a breakpoint) literally overnight.

Comment: @O.D, what do you mean with _if i dont click anything for some time_ ? Do you mean that VS stops debugging if you stop to interact with the C# service ?

Comment: @TLama: No but for example if i dont click to debug the next line it stops after Ca 30 Seconds

Comment: @O.D, have you resolved this somehow ? Was [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211464/how-can-i-avoid-timeout-errors-while-debugging-a-web-service-in-visual-studio-20) useful ?

Comment: @TLama: Thank you for the link but it did not really help, i found the solution somewhere else, i posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well guess i found the answer:

One have to stop the process status check by disabling the pinging property by following command:

**`appcmd set apppool /apppool.name: string /processModel.pingingEnabled: false`**

Or using the UI by:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. On the Connections pane, expand the server node and click Application Pools.
3. On the Application Pools page, select the application pool and then click Advanced Settings in the Actions pane.
4. For the Pinging Enabled property, select False to disable pinging, and then click OK.