# Problems with VS2008 debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

I am having a Problem to debug my code in VS2008, it just stops the debugging process and  sometimes my IDE crashes directly after that, i can't tell exactly when it happends but some configuration is causing this issue, any Ideas?

PS. My code has exception handling and it doesnt happen at a certain line of code but each time somewhere else, whats why i assume its no code issue.

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are debugging a Webservice try this:

```
appcmd set apppool /apppool.name: string /processModel.pingingEnabled: false
```

It helped in [my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338359/configuring-the-timeout-period-for-debugger-in-vs2008)

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify the project settings as explained on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se537z2t.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable the break on all exceptions, this way your execution will stop at first error.
Go to Debug->Exceptions->check the second line(clr exceptions).
If your ide crashes, you can also launch another instance of visual studio and attach it to the other one.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This case happends when your code undergoes recursive exception handling and may also if you have less ram memory when the IDE debugs, the later is  a rare case.